# Why does the while loop stop at 0 in this code?

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, decrement

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function declaration */
void func(void);

static int count = 5; /* global variable */

main() {

   while(count--) {
  func();
}

return 0;
}

/* function definition */
void func( void ) {

static int i = 5; /* local static variable */
i++;

printf("i is %d and count is %d\n", i, count);
}
```

I am looking at the while loop and there is no reason as to why it should stop at 0 however when count reaches 0, it stops. I try to set count as 0, and use -- and it went to -1 so there's no reason why this should stop at 0 from what I can see.

Comment: When `count` is zero, `while (count--)` evaluates to zero, or false, so the loop stops because the condition is no longer true (non-zero).  It could be written more verbosely as `while (count-- != 0)`. Remember that `count--` evaluates to the value of `count` before the decrement; if you want the decrement first, write `--count` (which returns the decremented value).

Comment: What do you mean "no reason" ? The loop condition of `0` is not a good enough reason?

Comment: I was not thinking about while thinking of count-- as false when it reaches 0.

Answer (score 1):

> however when count reaches 0, it stops

This is wrong conclusion, it stops when `count` reaches -1 and you can check it if you put print statement right after the loop. It does not execute loop body in that case, but that is how loop works.

Answer (score 0):

The `--` operator used after a variable applies last. When count is zero (evaluated as false), the condition is false, then it applies `count--` (so count is -1) and then exit the loop.

For your culture, you can do `--count`, it will decrement `count` before checking the condition.